# Non-zero sheaf cohomology

Tags: sheaf-theory, cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the real line with its usual topology. Does there exist a sheaf $F$ of abelian groups on $\mathbb{R}$ whose second cohomology group $H^{2}\left(\mathbb{R},F\right)$ is non-zero? What about $H^{j}\left(\mathbb{R},F\right)$ for integers $j\ge 2$ ?

(Here cohomology means derived functor cohomology as in, say, Hartshorne or EGA. Anyway this cohomology coincides with Cech cohomology since $\mathbb{R}$ is paracompact.)

Comment: What is R here?

Comment: @Ben- My guess: R is a commutative ring and the sheaf is on Spec(R).

Comment: Your question would certainly benefit from more info – what is R and what type of sheaf cohomology you are considering?

Comment: Now I agree with ilya, R is probably the real line.

Comment: Yes, R is the real line with its usual topology.
Cohomology is derived functor cohomology for the functor "Global Sections" (the cohomology used in Hartshorne or EGA, defined via injective resolutions) .
It coincides with Cech cohomology since R is paracompact.
@ilya n.  Could you please explain how the vanishing of cohomology in dimensions 2 and larger is a simple consequence of the definition of Cech cohomology ?
Of course I do not assume that my sheaf is constant (in which case even the first cohomology group would vanish).
Thanks to all for your interest.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong -- it's not obvious in Cech cohomology, at least as it's normally defined. The references though are any homological algebra course, post a different question about "what are the references" and you'll get lots of advice.

Comment: George -- I'd recommended that if you clarify your question in the comments, that you actually go back and edit the original question.

Comment: You should see an "edit" link right under the tags.

Comment: You should also be able to add comments to your own posts (you'll need 50 rep to add comments to other peoples' posts). There should be a "comment" link at the bottom of the post, or in situations like this were there are already lots of comments, it should be an "add/show X more comments" link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sheaf cohomology ${H}^i(X,F)$ of a (topological) manifold $X$ of dimension $n$ vanishes for $i > n$. This is a topological version of Grothendieck's vanishing theorem above. You can find this result in Kashiwara-Schapira's "[Sheaves on manifolds](http://books.google.com/books?id=qfWcUSQRsX4C&lpg=PA475&ots=Dk-Z-JgqhP&dq=kashiwara%20schapira%20sheaves%20on%20manifolds&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)" proposition III.3.2.2.

**Reference**

Masaki Kashiwara, Pierre Schapira, [Houzel, Christian]
*[Sheaves on manifolds. With a short history “Les débuts de la théorie des faisceaux”](http://books.google.com/books?id=qfWcUSQRsX4C&lpg=PA475&ots=Dk-Z-JgqhP&dq=kashiwara%20schapira%20sheaves%20on%20manifolds&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)* by Christian Houzel. (English)
Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, 292. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag, pp. x+512 (1990), [MR1074006](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1074006), [Zbl 0709.18001](https://zbmath.org/0709.18001).

Comment: Thank you,Abdo', you have given my question a definitive answer.
Congratulations on your erudition: I have the pleasant feeling I will read more from you on this site!

Comment: This holds true in much more generality actually: One has $H^i(X,F) = 0$ for $i > n$ where $n$ is the Lebesgue covering dimension of $X$, for every paracompact Hausdorff space $X$. For a proof see the book of Godement, II.5.12

Answer (score -4):

Since now we know that `R` in your question refers to real line equipped with standard topology,  sheaf cohomology will always have `H^i(F) = 0` for `i>1` — depending on how you define sheaf cohomology this is a theorem of different difficulty.